# supervisord prevents thread creation

Tags: python, node.js, multithreading, streaming, supervisord

I'm developing a web app with Angular/Flask as back-end. When clicking on a button, I start a thread to run a video streaming with node.

This works fine when server is launched with Python command. Then I run the app with supervisor:

```
supervisorctl start myapp
```

After clicking, the thread is not launched. There's no error, nor warning: no log at all.

Is it possible that supervisor blocks the thread? http://supervisord.org/subprocess.html

> Programs meant to be run under supervisor should not daemonize themselves. Instead, they should run in the foreground. They should not detach from the terminal from which they are started.

Comment: No clue what your code looks like, especially the forking code.

Comment: Unlikely anyone can reproduce your issues reliably with the little info you give. Provide a minimal but complete recipe how to do that. Oh, and btw, don't just add your interpretation ("prevents thread creation") but state the observed facts, too. Concerning your "no error, nor warning: no log at all", is the code actually started then?

Comment: Sorry my title was misleading. I've not provided many details at first, to see if someone observed that too; but I will.
Yes, the code is started, I mean there's no log for the node process.